# Separated Vuex for each Vue instance on the page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I’m instantiating multiple Vue apps on the page:

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import useStore from "./store";

const arr = [1, 2];
for (const index of arr) {
  const store = useStore();

  new Vue({
    router,
    store,
    render: (h) => h(App)
  }).$mount(`#app$_{index}`);
}
```

My store file looks like this:

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

import address from "./modules/address";

export default function useStore() {
  return new Vuex.Store({
    modules: { address }
  });
}
```

And address module:

```js
const state = {
  address: null
};

const getters = {
  address(state) {
    return state.address;
  }
};

const mutations = {
  setAddress(state, address) {
    state.address = address;
  }
};

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  getters,
  mutations
};
```

But the store seems to be shared across the all Vue instances on the page.
Why, when I’m creating a new instance for each Vue app?

Thanks

Comment: As with cookies the browser goes by host AFAIK. If the stores have shared fields you might have to implement a prefix per store instantiated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't Vuex store being shared across multiple Vue instances, it is actually the Address module's state getting shared across multiple Vuex stores.

Vuex docs address this issue: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#module-reuse

> If we use a plain object to declare the state of the module, then that state object will be shared by reference and cause cross store/module state pollution when it's mutated.

Just change your address module state declaration from plain object definition to function definition:

```
const state = () => ({
  address: null
});
```

And you're good to go!